# Finding Images in Go To Anything

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

Now that sublime has a nice image viewer, is it possible to search for images in Go To Anything <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure of a way to do it on a project-specific basis, but you can get images to show up in Go To Anything by default, then exclude them from specific projects.

In `Preferences > Settings - Default`, change:

```
"binary_file_patterns": ["*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.gif", "*.ttf", "*.tga", "*.dds", "*.ico", "*.eot", "*.pdf", "*.swf", "*.jar", "*.zip"],
```

to

```
"binary_file_patterns": ["*.dds", "*.ico", "*.eot", "*.pdf", "*.swf", "*.jar", "*.zip"],
```

If you don't want images popping up in Go To Anything for a particular project, you'll have to exclude them in the project's settings with `Project > Edit Project`.

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "/path/to/project",
            "file_exclude_patterns": ["*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.gif", "*.ttf", "*.tga"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just put insert filename of the photo and It'll show up in search results.
Searching by extension also works :
[image]

Comment: This doesn't work because most image file extensions are ignored with the setting: `binary_file_patterns`.